# Which gets precedence when Converting Constructor as well as Conversion Operator are defined and why compilers differ this conversion?

Tags: c++, type-conversion

What does standard say about the precedence of **Converting Constructor** and **Conversion Operator**, in simple language?

Also, I can see that when I have 2 classes `myClass` and `otherClass` and I want to convert `otherClass` to `myClass` as shown below, then Conversion operator gets called for class `otherClass`

`myClass mc = otherclass();//creates temp for otherClass`

This behavior is same in gcc as well as MSVC.

But this behavior is different across above compilers when I do something like below-

```
otherClass oC;
myClass mc = oC;//for gcc (C++11): Ambiguous, for MSVC: calls myClass Conversion Constructor
```

So, my question is why initializing from temporary in 1st case is different than the 2nd case? And secondly why compilers differ behavior for 2nd case?

EDIT: Classes defined as

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class otherClass;
class myClass {
      public:
          myClass(){}
          myClass(otherClass&) {
          cout << "called myClass's conversion constructor" << endl;
          }
};

class otherClass {
      public:
         operator myClass () {
             cout << "called otherClass's conversion operator" << endl;
             return myClass ();
         }
};

int main()
{
    otherClass oc;
    myClass mc = oc;
    myClass mc1 = otherClass();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The formal code behind the latter example which (apparently) delivers dissimilar results between g++ and msvc would be highly illuminating to your question. I.e. include the class sources and a driving main. I.e. a [mcve], regardless of how trivial you think it may be, including versions of said-same toolchains.

Comment: Show the code. There are several things that could affect this.

Comment: That's still not a [mre]. A full example has #includes, a `main`, etc. In this case, it would be good to have something to output so we can tell whether a converting constructor or conversion function is actually called.

Comment: Updated with complete code aschepler

Comment: `myClass(otherClass&)` should be `myClass(const otherClass&)`, btw. That should address the ambiguity your gcc run is complaining about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Which gets precedence when Converting Constructor as well as Conversion Operator are defined

Neither.

> why compilers differ this conversion?

If the conversion sequence is ambiguous, then the program is ill formed. Thus the compiler is allowed to not produce a program, and required to diagnose the issue. Allowing such ambiguous conversion intentionally would be considered a language extension, but failing to diagnose regardless of the extension would be a failure to conform to the standard.

If the conversion sequence is unambiguous, and there is no other reason for the program to be ill formed, then a compiler that refuses to compile it does not conform to the standard.

---

Edit: Regarding the added example: The conversion of `myClass mc = oc` is indeed ambiguous and the program is ill-formed. So, a possible reason for difference in behaviour is either a language extension of the compiler that allows it, or a compiler bug. If it is not diagnosed, then the compiler does not conform to the standard. I recommend disabling language extensions.

`myClass mc1 = otherClass()` is well-formed because there is only one valid candidate for the conversion. The converting constructor is not a valid candidate because lvalue references to non-const cannot be bound to rvalues.

Comment: Thanks eerorika. But what is happening behind scenes in case of temporary converting to my class, facilitating same behavior on both compilers.

Comment: Thanks eerorika for reminding rvalue binding. After disabling language extension in MSVC, I could see the consistent behavior with gcc.